# C++/CLI Timer freezes applications

Tags: winforms, timer, c++-cli

I am using a timer in a c++ windows form app. To handle receiving messages sent from a server using WinSock2. The current code for my timer is,

```
private: System::Void tmrMessages_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

int ID;
char* cID = new char[64];
char* message = new char[256];

ZeroMemory(cID, 64);
ZeroMemory(message, 256);
if(recv(sConnect, message, 256, NULL) != SOCKET_ERROR && recv(sConnect, cID, 64, NULL) != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    ID = atoi(cID);
    if (ID == 1)
    {
        lbxMessages->Items->Add("hello");
    }
    }
}
```

I didn't have it add the variables to the listbox because I wanted to test and make sure it worked first. It DOES work but, it makes the app so slow that it doesn't allow any user input at all.  It does show the listbox being updated but, like I said doesn't allow me to move the window, click textboxes or anything. If you have any idea why this is happening please let me know.

thanks.

Comment: There are better ways to handle incoming socket data, but that should work too.  What's the timer interval?

Comment: @BenVoigt the interval was originally 100ms but then I already thought maybe that was the problem so I set it to 1000ms. Suffice to say it didn't solve the problem haha.

Comment: You're also leaking the memory you allocate with `new char[64]` and `new char[256]`.

Answer (score 1):

If those are blocking reads, they'll freeze the UI thread until you get data.

What you should do is set non-blocking mode and read until you fill your buffer, which may take multiple `recv` calls, the process it.

I really like `WSAAsyncSelect` for this... it automatically puts the socket into non-blocking mode and sends your window a message whenever data is available.  You can easily handle that message by overriding `WndProc`.

It should be pretty straightforward:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

const unsigned WM_SOCKETREADY = WM_USER + 100;
```

...

when you open the socket (assuming that's a member function of the form), call

```
WSAAsyncSelect(sConnect, HWND(Handle.ToPointer()), WM_SOCKETREADY, FD_READ);
```

and then `WndProc` (which you should override) will have the message delivered to it

```
virtual void WndProc( Message% m ) override
{
    switch (m.Msg) {
        case WM_SOCKETREADY:
            ReadSocketHandler();
            return;

        default:
            Form::WndProc(m);
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you could give an example? I'm not THAT familiar with winsock. I am really just doing this as a learning experience.

Comment: error C3861: 'ReadSocketHandler': identifier not found |`AND`|

error C2562: 'winformClient1::Form1::WndProc' : 'void' function returning a value |`AND`|

error C3252: 'winformClient1::Form1::WndProc' : cannot reduce accessibility of a virtual method in a managed type

Comment: @Ian: You need to provide `ReadSocketHandler`... some of the `recv` stuff you've already written should work.  For the second error, just get rid of `return`.  For the last one, you need to put `protected:`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by provide? sorry if I am sounding like a noob haha.

Comment: Also I had to change `WSAAsyncSelect(sConnect, HWND(Handle), WM_SOCKETREADY, FD_READ);` to `WSAAsyncSelect(sConnect, HWND(&Handle), WM_SOCKETREADY, FD_READ);' For it to work. I just want to make sure that isn't going to mess anything up.

Comment: @Ian: That would break things.  Try `HWND(Handle.ToPointer())` instead.

Comment: Okay I did that but, can you please explain to me what you mean by "provide `ReadSockerHandler()`"? Thanks for all this help by the way haha.

Comment: @Ian: Write a function with that name.  Or a different name of your choice.  Basically everything that your timer event handler was doing before.

Comment: what `does Message% m` represent?

Comment: Also am I supposed to call WndProc in the timer? or where am I supposed to call it?

Comment: @Ian: `WndProc` is a built-in function.  Windows (it's actually even more fundamental than .NET) calls it when any message arrives, such as timer or mouse click or form resizing, or in our case, socket activity.  .NET has a default version that calls event handlers for buttons and timers, but it knows nothing about socket activity.  So we write one to call the socket handler when the message arrives, and let .NET do its normal thing with all other messages.  You don't call `WndProc`, Windows will do that.  You won't need the timer any more, since now your event will be triggered by socket data

Comment: That is what I thought but, nothing happens it doesn't add the item to the listbox like it should. I called `WSAAsyncSelect(sConnect, HWND(Handle.ToPointer()), WM_SOCKETREADY, FD_READ);` right after the `connect()` function. and everything else is setup like you said. Nothing happens when I send data from the server to the client, unlike when I used the timer. Any ideas?